# Delivering SQLServer based app on client System

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2012

how can i manage connection string of an ADO.net Object model dynamically?

i have connected my application to database using Entity Framework and connection string is automatically added to app.config. how can i get list of available servers and change connections string based on that in the run-time?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? What research have you done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 5.0 & dynamic connection string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364617/ef-5-0-dynamic-connection-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because VS adds the connection string to app.config by default it doesn't mean that is a good idea and if you do keep the connection string there you cannot change it at run time.

One solution is to keep **encrypted** connection string in your settings and that will allow you to dynamically change it at run time by simply calling:

```
Settings.Default.Save();
```

and

```
Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Comment: thanks guys...for getting list of available SQL Servers i found this which i hope work over lan network too:DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
            for (int i = 0; i < servers.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(servers.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()); ///// used to get the servers in the local machine////
            }